# Optimized query in laravel with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, vuejs2

I have 3 model: **Tag, Post, User**, and map them with **TagPost, TagUser** model.

When User search Tag in input search, I using $http.post (VUE) and send array tag selected to Server.

**Example tags print in server:**

```
array:2 [
      0 => array:10 [
        "id" => 197
        "name" => "nisi"
        "slugify" => "nisi"
        "thumbnail" => "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/?85397"
        "seo_title" => null
        "seo_description" => null
        "seo_keyword" => null
        "cover" => null
        "created_at" => "2017-06-13 07:19:30"
        "updated_at" => "2017-06-04 06:01:14"
      ]
      1 => array:10 [
        "id" => 184
        "name" => "dolores"
        "slugify" => "dolores"
        "thumbnail" => "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/?45793"
        "seo_title" => null
        "seo_description" => null
        "seo_keyword" => null
        "cover" => null
        "created_at" => "2017-06-08 15:37:59"
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-27 13:34:02"
      ]
    ]
```

I want when user search tags then view update users and posts have tags user search.

**View here:**

[image]

**In server (laravel) how to code with relationship model using least query?**

Comment: Might this helps you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly set your relationship this should work

```
Tag::with('posts','users')->whereIn('id', $your_ids_send_by_vue)->get();
```

And then in your controller do the logic to get your desired data